# How to pass value as string array to json key in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to pass the payload as `{ "names": [ "abc", "xyz" ]}` to my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I am trying like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EmpDetails>>> GetDetails([FromBody] string[] names)
```

I am getting only values not key name in payload.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a class

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EmpDetails>>> GetDetails([FromBody]Data names)

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("names")]
    public List<Names> Names { get; set; }
}

public enum Names
{
    abc,
    xyz
};
```

or if you want just strings, your class should be

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("names")]
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```